# android: am pm format of alarm

Tags: android

I am using the alarmmanger class set method for setting the alarm. i 
 takes the input from user through timepicker dialog for setting the 
 alarm.alarm work fine when i set specific hour and minutes but 
 application is not following the am/pm logic. mean if i set the alarm
 10:31 am while in system time is 10:30 pm then alarm invoke at 10:31  pm not at 10:30 am.anyone tell me whats the reason?

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
        //time.set(Calendar.AM_PM);



        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: please suggest regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the time with the time format using SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat class which will give the date based on the date-time string and get that value using getTime and set into the alarm in set method.

Or you can do another way get the alarm time and check whether it's **am** or **pm** and set this attribute into the calendar object with time and date and get millisecond value from the calendar set into the alarm.set() method.

Hope you get some idea/suggestion

**Edit**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); // this is you format
Date d = sdf.parse("19/12/2011 03:47:00 pm"); // this string getting you from your timepicker
Intent myIntent = new Intent(youractivity.this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(youractivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, d.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Note: you need to put into the try and catch block parse part it may be cause error during parsing time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. can u put piece of code for the first suggestion. so i understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method in setting alarm:

```
    /**
     * Set the Alarm
     *
     * @param context  the activity context
     * @param id       the alarm ID for this app
     * @param hour     the alarm hour
     * @param minute   the alarm minute
     * @param timeZone the timezone am = Calendar.AM or pm = Calendar.PM
     */
    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int id, int hour, int minute, int timeZone) {
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, timeZone);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, 0);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pIntent);
    }
```

For the timezone parameter use either am = `Calendar.AM` or pm = `Calendar.PM`

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line:

```
time.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
```

to

```
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
```